# Does anyone know what Bhodisattva this figurine represents?

Tags: bodhisattva

I purchased this beautiful figurine, but actually I have no idea what exactly it represents. Maybe somebody can tell me more about the symbolism in it (including the mudra)?

[image]

Comment: The iconography — particularly the head-piece and dual lotus flowers — makes me think this is one of the manifestations of Tara (a Tibetan Buddha and a Mahayana bodhisattva). But I've never seen a Tara with crossed hands; the ubiquitous Green Tara is presented with open hands (left raised, right lowered).

Answer (score 1):

This is a statue of Vajradhara, the primordial Buddha sitting in Virasana with his hands in a Vajrahumkara mudra.